Kalman Filter with sensitivity to the parameters
We all know the most crucial part of Kalman Filter is the calibration of process noise and observation noise covariance matrices. ($R$ and $Q$ in Wikipedia convention )
Frequently we don't really know $R$ and $Q$. And our Kalman Filter can be sensitive to the parameters tuning of $R$ and $Q$. Is there a way to design a Kalman Filter that factors in the sensitivity to the parameters.
One solution I have in mind is that somehow come up with a penalty term when we minimize trace of $P_{k|k}$ with respect to Kalman Gain $K$ like here. The penalty term should describe how sensitive the estimation error woul be with respect to the parameters.
But I believe I can't be the first person to worry about about this problem. Is there an existing solution? In my particular use case the noise process $Q$ is more noisy, observation noise $R$ less so.
[EDIT] I found the $H_{\infty}$ Filter idea pretty interesting. But the problem is $H_{\infty}$ Filter assumes no knowledge of $R$ and $Q$. But I do have some knowledge, just that I want my filter to robust to noise

It sounds you're looking for a method of generating a filter that's insensitive to process variations or model error.  Look at the H-infinity filter: it's not what you describe, but it may do what you really need a filter to do.

@TimWescott thanks. It is indeed a neat solution. However H-infinity filter makes no assumption about the covariance matrixes. I have a decent guess of my covariance matrices though..

If you're willing to read through a paper and really understand the derivations, here is one that balances the sensitivity and the robustness metrics of the Kalman filter.
The underlying principle is to reduce the covariance of the innovation term (difference between the prediction and the measurement), and get a balance between sensitivity (adaptability to measurement noise) and robustness (adaptability to modelling error) of the filter. A sensitivity metric shows the effect of the measurement noise covariance, R, on the innovation covariance matrix. A robustness metric measures the effect of the process noise covariance, Q, on the state-dependent component of the innovation covariance matrix. To get a balance between robustness and sensitivity, the two metrics are plotted for a variety of Q, and the Q for which the two metrics intersect is chosen.
In most applications, estimating the measurement noise covariance, R, is achievable because some statistic of the measurement noise is known a-priori, or can be measured.

Thanks. Is there a "mature" method that sort of made itself into a textbook or some sort? :) I have read many papers, but they all seem to have different approaches. I dont need something that's too novel or state of arts, I'm just wondering about an existing mature solution ...
